# Rails: ActionView::Template::Error - undefined method 'comment'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a problem with rendering form for input data. The controller looks like this:

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @ad = current_user.ads.build()
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => 'new' }# new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @ad }
    end
  end
end
```

In the view (the relevant parts):

```
<%= form_for ([@ad.user, @ad]) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.label 'Description' %></div>
  <%= f.text_area :comment, cols:35, rows:4 %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And the model:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :url, :comment, :category_id, :layout, :user_id
  ...
end
```

When I render the form, I get the error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `comment' for
>
> ## )

It's weird, because on localhost it's working, but after uploading the app to Heroku I am getting that error.

Where could be a problem?

Comment: Did you make sure to migrate your database? rake db::migrate?  I think that was the cause of mine some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Check your migrations:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate:status
```

Confirm that you've ran all migrations. Heroku does not automatically run your migrations when you push new code.

Run `$ heroku run rake db:migrate` to run them.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the heroku dyno worked for me

```
$ heroku ps:restart
```

Answer (score 0):

My database migrations were all up to date, so restarting the heroku dyno fixed this problem for me. I ran:

`heroku ps:restart`